# Renaming existing CarrierWave files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

How do you rename existing images with CarrierWave? (This question is close but not really the same: [Renaming uploaded files with Carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443494/renaming-uploaded-files-with-carrierwave)) For example, if `model.image.url` is `foo-bar-jpg` how can I rename both the file and and the corresponding database field to `foo-bar.jpg`?

`model.image.recreate_versions!` will create new files but in the database it doesn't change the model's image field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the technique described here: [How to assign a remote file to Carrierwave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007575/how-to-assign-a-remote-file-to-carrierwave)

This may not be the best way to go, but it worked for me.  My remote file just happened to be the old file name/path.

First, I changed the Carrierwave uploader to have the new file name style I wanted.  Then I wrote a rake task to iterate through the records and update the files like this:

```
model.remote_image_url = old_image_url
model.save!
```

This will upload the existing file again, setting the name/path based on your updated Uploader (and recreate all versions).  I haven't tackled the issue of cleaning up the old files yet, I'm not sure how this will work if your store_dir is the same (mine changed as well).

Make sure to test thoroughly on a few records before running through your full table, its easy to make a mess of things.  Be aware that changing your store_dir will break all of your lookups for existing files.

Answer (score 2):

The [locomotive branch](https://github.com/locomotivecms/carrierwave) of Carrierwave seems to have rename support - the specific file is [here](https://github.com/locomotivecms/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/rename.rb).

There is [file rename support](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/commit/09529283c0243e7bd1071e659827463776e1ad4a) in the main when you convert file types, but no rename support:

```
"This should help with situations where a file has multiple versions,
and at least one of the versions is of a different format than the master version."
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this, it seems like outdated, but maybe helps someone:
`https://github.com/stvkoch/carrierwave_single_store`